# Preparing simple multipart/alternative email using MimeMessageHelper (Spring Framework)

Tags: java, spring, email, mime, jakarta-mail

I'd like to prepare simple html email with alternative plain-text version.
I don't need any attachments or inline elements.

By default if I use:

```
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
```

I get `MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED` mode.

My email content body looks like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_8_21489995.1282317482209"

------=_Part_8_21489996.1282317482209
Content-Type: multipart/related; 
    boundary="----=_Part_9_21489996.1282317482209"

------=_Part_9_21489996.1282317482209
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_10_2458205.1282317482209"

------=_Part_10_2458205.1282317482209
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Simple newsletter.

------=_Part_10_2458205.1282317482209
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple newsletter</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <p>Simple newsletter.</p>
    </body>
<html>

------=_Part_10_2458205.1282317482209--

------=_Part_9_21489996.1282317482209--

------=_Part_8_21489995.1282317482209--
```

What can I do to get rid of mixed and related boundries?

Ideal solution would be `MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_ALTERNATIVE` mode, but it's not available.

Answer (score 6):

Because of a spam checker issue, I was looking to send html email with alternative but it seems that spring just don't provide a simple MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_ALTERNATIVE. However using  the MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED get my emails reach their destinations.

If you still want to get rid of mixed and related boundaries, you need more control over how a MIME message is assembled, you can create an implementation of the MimeMessagePreparator interface and pass this to the JavaMailSender.send() method in place of the MimeMessage.

```
  sender.send(new MessagePreparator());
```

```
private class MessagePreparator implements MimeMessagePreparator {
       public void prepare(MimeMessage msg) throws Exception {
           // set header details
           msg.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse(from));
           msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
           msg.setSubject(subject);
                                                       
            // create wrapper multipart/alternative part
            MimeMultipart ma = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
            msg.setContent(ma);
            // create the plain text
            BodyPart plainText = new MimeBodyPart();
            plainText.setText("This is the plain text version of the mail.");
            ma.addBodyPart(plainText);
            // create the html part
            BodyPart html = new MimeBodyPart();
            html.setContent(
                    "<html><head></head><body>
<h1>This is the HTML version of the mail."
                             + "</h1></body></html>", "text/html");
            ma.addBodyPart(html);
        }
    }
}
```

The order in which you add BodyPart instances to the MimeMultipart is important, and you should add the BodyPart with the most preferable message format last.

> This is an excerpt taken from Pro Spring 2.5 chapter13 - § Sending an HTML Message with a Plain Text Alternative ; APRESS ISBN-13 (pbk): 978-1-59059-921-1

Answer (score 4):

There is also simper way to do that:

```
MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");
messageHelper.setFrom("your@mail.com");
messageHelper.setTo("target@mail.com");
messageHelper.setSubject("Spring mail test");
messageHelper.setText("Plain message", "<html><body><h2>html message</h2></body></html>");
javaMailSender.send(message);
```